# Use Eigen::Vector4d as 3d in simpler way

Tags: c++, c++20, eigen

**Windows 10** /
**eigen3 3.4.0-1** /
**MSYS2/MinGW64 13.1.0** /
**c++20**

To take advantage of SIMD vectorization, I am planning to use vector4d as vector3d. To make code less confusing and more user-friendly, Here is the implementation

```cpp
typedef Eigen::Vector4d Vec3;
```

The problem is when I create a vec using

```cpp
Vec3 u(1,2,3);
```

the compiler shows errors because of 4th missing value. The correct syntax is:

```cpp
Vec3 u(1,2,3,4);
```

but again this makes the code more confusing. On the MSVC compiler, you can have the same type and function names. Example:

```cpp
typedef Eigen::Vector4d Vec3;
inline Eigen::Vector4d Vec3(double x, double y, double z) {
     return Eigen::Vector4d(x, y, z, 0.0);
}
inline Eigen::Vector4d Vec3() {
     return Eigen::Vector4d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

Vec3 v = Vec3(1,2,3);
Vec3 w = Vec3();
```

Unfortunately, this feature is not available on g++/gcc. Considering everything here is my final implementation:

```cpp
typedef Eigen::Vector4d Vec3;
inline Eigen::Vector4d Vec3Init(double x, double y, double z) {
     return Eigen::Vector4d(x, y, z, 0.0);
}
inline Eigen::Vector4d Vec3Init() {
     return Eigen::Vector4d(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0);
}

Vec3 v = Vec3Init(1,2,3);
Vec3 w = Vec3Init();
```

Any ideas to make life easier?

Comment: Have a look at the unsupported (and apparently undocumented) `unsupported/Eigen/AlignedVector3` module (you may need to browse the source code for that).

Answer (score 0):

You can make a class that inherits from `Eigen::Vector4d` and overload (of sorts) the constructor to take 3 arguments.  The downside is that you will always get that 4th value.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

class Vec3 : public Eigen::Vector4d {

public:
Vec3(double x, double y, double z, double foo = 0.0) : Eigen::Vector4d(x, y, z, foo){}

};

int main(int argc, char * argv []){

    Vec3 vec3 = Vec3(1,2,3);
    std::cout << vec3 << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Here is the output of that code.

> 1
> 2
> 3
> 0

There maybe side effects of this such as taking cross products or matrix multiplication where you may not want a 4x1 vector under the hood doing things.  I also don't know which (if any) additional overloads you would need.